# Добавление GameObject в RecorderController

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я использую библиотеку Unity Recorder https://docs.unity.cn/Packages/com.unity.recorder@2.1/api/. У меня есть такой код, он должен сохранять движения объекта в анимацию

```cs
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEditor.Recorder;
using UnityEngine;

public class RecordGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    RecorderController m_RecorderController;
    public GameObject _gameObject;

    void OnEnable()
    {

        var controllerSettings = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<RecorderControllerSettings>();
        m_RecorderController = new RecorderController(controllerSettings);

        var imageRecorder = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<AnimationRecorderSettings>();
        imageRecorder.RecordMode = 0;
        imageRecorder.OutputFile = ("Assets/Recordings/");
        imageRecorder.name = "anim_Shadow";



        controllerSettings.AddRecorderSettings(imageRecorder);
        controllerSettings.SetRecordModeToManual();
        m_RecorderController.PrepareRecording();
        m_RecorderController.
        m_RecorderController.StartRecording();
    }
}
```

Но т.к я не добавил объект, который надо записывать, unity выдает ошибку `[AnimationRecorder: anim_Shadow] Recording failed. No assigned game object to record`. Как мне добавить GameObject и исправить эту ошибку?